# Using Smarty in Javascript in PHPStorm

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, smarty, phpstorm

I recently switched to PHPStorm and it's great, but
I have a bunch of .js files that contain Smarty tags to insert a bit of scaffolding; but this breaks PHPStorm's syntax checker, highlighting all my code in red because it's not seeing the opening tags that the smarty tag will insert.

```
{include file="../../WidgetClassStart.js"}

    return widgets_Base.extend( {
```

The error is "'return' outside function definition".

Can I get PHPStorm's syntax checker / compiler to either evaluate the Smarty tag's contents or ignore this specific pattern (since it's the same everywhere) for that specific error?

Comment: Same problem - The code base I must work in does this everywhere, so there are red lines under everything. It makes it impossible to see other errors or warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up putting a

```
var widget;
```

in WidgetClassStart.js;

In every widget I replaced "return ..." with

```
widget = ...
```

And then I return *that* var in the WidgetClassEnd.js file,

```
return widget;
```

so now WidgetClassEnd.js is the only place this error occurs and all my widgets are at least free from red squiggly lines.